# How to Extract nth line String after Pattern match in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pattern-matching

I have a text file with below content, all i need to extract **`<a href="https://support.oracle.com/******">29565618></a>`** after Specific String Match(highlighted/bold below)

`<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle`**JDK**`8 Update 212 <strong>`**(public)**`</strong></div>`

**Note:** The href tag is above on the 2nd line after this patter match in the input text file.

---

**Input Text File:**

```
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29565618">29565618</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle **JDK** 8 Update 212 <strong>(**public**)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206839">29206839</a></td>
<td class="km">Oracle JRE 8 Update 211 Enterprise Installer</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206838">29206838</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle SERVER JRE 8 Update 211 <strong>(public)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206859">29206859</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle Java SE Embedded 8 Update 211 <strong>(public)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
29565618
```

---

**My Code:**

```
    with open('file.txt') as f:
        my_list = list(f)
        try:
            if my_list.index('JDK') > 0 and my_list.index('public') > 0:
                print(string[4:-4])
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Beautiful Soup like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29565618">29565618</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle **JDK** 8 Update 212 <strong>(**public**)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206839">29206839</a></td>
<td class="km">Oracle JRE 8 Update 211 Enterprise Installer</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206838">29206838</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle SERVER JRE 8 Update 211 <strong>(public)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206859">29206859</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle Java SE Embedded 8 Update 211 <strong>(public)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

trs = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in trs:
    if tr.div:
        div_text = tr.div.get_text()
        if "JDK" in div_text and "public" in div_text:
            for td in tr.find_all('td'):
                td_text = td.get_text()
                if td_text.isdigit():
                    print(td_text)
```

Output:

```
29565618
```

Answer (score 1):

If `data` is your HTML snippet from the question, this script:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('td.km:has(~ td.km) > a'):
    if re.findall(r' JDK.*?\(public\)', a.find_next('td', class_='km').text):
        print(a.text)
```

prints:

```
29565618
```

Comment: @AndrejKesely https://bpaste.net/VGYQ can we do it like that way ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Idea is OK, but this prints `None` for me. The `(public)` is in inside other tag than "JDK" - so you need to check for this somehow. The `findPreviousSibling()` should be `find_previous("a")` IMHO

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Something similarly to this https://bpaste.net/FDPA

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

match = soup.find(text=lambda t: "JDK" in t)
if match and 'public' in match.parent.text:
    print(match.find_previous('a').text)
```

Thanks for `@Andrej Kesely`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(?=<a.*?>(.*)</a>)
```

Check here, it uses your data to confirm the match: https://regex101.com/r/W2wV2I/1/

Comment: I matched for your expected output, which was a number. My apologies if i read this wrong. But it does only match that number, nothing else

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html = ''' <tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29565618">29565618</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle **JDK** 8 Update 212 <strong>(**public**)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206839">29206839</a></td>
<td class="km">Oracle JRE 8 Update 211 Enterprise Installer</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206838">29206838</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle SERVER JRE 8 Update 211 <strong>(public)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="km"><a href="https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?patchId=29206859">29206859</a></td>
<td class="km">
<div title="Available on both MOS and OTN">Oracle Java SE Embedded 8 Update 211 <strong>(public)</strong></div>
</td>
<td class="km">16-APR-2019</td>
</tr>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
trs = doc.trs.contains(['JDK','public'])
for tr in trs:
  print(tr.a.text) # 29565618
```